# I'm getting different results from the console and innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I've created a simple website that generates an excel formula based on the arguments given by the user. The console output works perfectly but when I display the output in HTML it doesn't work. Maybe the newline characters are messing up with the if statements.

Long story short, which HTML element should I display my code in to get the same result from the console?

```
function generate(){
    let col = document.getElementById("col").value.toUpperCase();
    let args = document.getElementById("args").value;
    let argArray = args.split('_');
    let numArgs = argArray.length;

    //String Preparation
    let string = `=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(FORM!${col}2:${col}), "", IFS(`
    for (let i = 0; i < numArgs; i++){
        string += `FORM!${col}2:${col} = "${argArray[i]}", DB!${col}${i+2}`;
        if (i+1 !== numArgs){
            string += `, `;
        }
    }
    string += `))`

    //Display result
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = string;
    console.log(string);
}
```

Comment: post your code:)

Comment: Can you show an example of your code so we can better understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: What is the formula, you probably use some characters that are illegal in html.

Comment: Can you also show what `console.log(string)` is printing to the console?

Comment: try escaping the output as I suggest in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT I think that your problem is related to character escaping in html.

Using the [Underscore library](https://underscorejs.org/#escape)

You can try with `_.escape` to escape the string before printing it on HTML.

It goes like `var escapedFomula = _.escape("formula")`

Comment: Implementing a complete library might be overkill if it's only used to fix one small issue.

Comment: First, those are utility libraries that would save you tons of lines of common problems already solved out-of-the-box. Second I mentioned lodash but I was thinking about Underscore that's why edited the answer. Underscore is just as 60kb with comments and everything, 6.5kb minified and gzipped as of 2019 we're in 6.5kb should not be a problem. But, in any case those libraries are FOSS so you can copy-paste the actual method from source.